# How to make Ionic app work with an API written in Laravel but still works offline

Tags: angularjs, laravel, mobile, ionic-framework

I would like to ask how to create an ionic app that talks to Laravel API but still works offline when there's no connection.

Let's say i have to write a quiz mobile app in Ionic and it requests for Laravel API to retrieve the questions as well as store the scores in db.

I'm just starting to learn Ionic and i'm really confused right now on how to approach this.

What confuses me most are:

1. Does the Ionic source live inside the Laravel source code w/c serves the API?
2. If i want the Ionic app to be installable, should the Laravel source code be included as well during the compilation process?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In the few details you provided, I can say the Laravel code does not live inside the ionic app. The ionic app is separate from the backend API by Laravel. You are possibly trying for a ReST based architecture where you communicate with your Laravel Server with an API. You need to keep those codes separate.

However without any internet, you won't be able to access those APIs, so you will just be able to show some static data, or you could serve from a DB and show later. For how to use the sqlite db you can look [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/%22here%22)

In your backend you can have an API like

> http://example.com/api/v1/questions/1/

Which will fetch a question with options and if you want the app to have the answer for offline storage you may have that as well. When a user answers, you may check whether you have internet access and send answer and verify if you do, else you may save the answer in your DB and sync when you do have access. You can fetch multiple questions so that a user may answer multiple questions in case he/she will not have internet access.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah, i use Laravel for a RESTful API and connect thru $http w/ Angular. I followed some tutorials on the net where the ionic source code is inside the Laravel code base.

What approach would be the best and easiest to take to achieve offline synchronization? Currently i'm planning on Laravel with MySql/SQlite for the backend but it seems thru searching the net, PouchDB + Couchdb always appears. Would i just completely abandon Laravel and go let's say Express and Pouchdb.

Would that be easier?

Comment: If you are already comfortable with Laravel, you can easily use it. There is no need to go for Express just for that reason. The RESTful APIs through $http would work great with any backend. Remember, if you need some sort of offline storage, there will be 2 databases not 1. One of the backend, one of the frontend(frontend being your ionic app). For the same I have already provided you with the link. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your php or in general server side code is completely independent from your ionic application. If you want your app to work offline you should think about something like fetching a high number of information initially and work with this data without making any additional requests.

However your ionic app does only contain the frontend. You could implement some logic for local storage, but if you want to keep information hidden from the user (e.g. solutions) you have to put that logic on a dedicated server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm not great at explaining things. But, to put it simply, i followed some tutorials where the Ionic app is inside the Laravel code base. And their completely independent, Angular just uses $http service to access API exposed by Laravel.

My concern concern is with offline data synchronization, is Laravel + MySQL the way to go here?

Comment: you would have to write a service, which checks if connection is available and if yes, syncs. frameworks such as meteor already take care of such things.